# How do you pull data from one sheet to another and have one just pulling the last row of data automatically when one is entered? I need rows A1-AO

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to pull data from a master copy and the only data that I need pulled needs to go onto another spreadsheet but only the most current. I need the whole row and it contains words and numbers. The rows that are needed are A1-AO. How can this be done?

Comment: Most current is determined from someone filling out a Google Form.

Comment: Yes, via timestamp.

Comment: Right now, the information is A1-AO, and it says there is a circular reference.

Comment: Ok. I will edit the request.

Comment: It says there is an error "MATCH range must be a single row or a column." I have the IMPORTRANGE on sheet 1 pulling from the master copy and sheet 2 with the match formula pulling data from sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A1:AO500, MATCH(1,--ISBLANK(A1:A500),0)-1))
```

Upto the first 500 rows, the last non blank row will be chosen and returned.

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Sheet1'!A1:AO500, MATCH(1,--ISBLANK('Sheet1'!A1:A500),0)-1))
```

***EDIT: Killed bugs with the MATCH formula***

Comment: If the formula solved your problem, Mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @pnuts The Most current will always be in the last row. The Google forms is populated like that. There will be no missing it.

Comment: @Spencer Lee Haff I have edited the MATCH formula correctly. Kindly try again. And comment here. I don't have previleges to comment on your first post.

Comment: If it works, Mark this post as the correct answer. The ✔✓✅ mark on the left of this post